# How do I post an image and some text to a company's Facebook page from a SPA?

Tags: facebook, single-page-application

How do I post an image and some text to a company Facebook page from a SPA?

I'm trying to figure out from [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/) what I need.

I have a mobile (intended for business use) web app (SPA) that I want to post from, so using [share](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/web) feels incorrect as it expects an existing HTML page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be the correct endpoint: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.3/page/photos#Creating

You can do a POST request to `/me/photos` with a Page Token of that Page. The Token needs to have the `publish_pages` permission authorized.